# Comparator in stl

Tags: c++, stl

```
struct Interval
{
    int start, end;
};

// Compares two intervals according to staring times.
bool compareInterval(Interval i1, Interval i2)
{
    return (i1.start < i2.start);
}

int main()
{
    Interval arr[] =  { {6,8}, {1,9}, {2,4}, {4,7} };
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    // sort the intervals in increasing order of
    // start time
    sort(arr, arr+n, compareInterval);
```

*compareInterval will return either true or false but how does sort function will take 0 and 1 as argument and sort according to compareIntervals as the sort function will look like either sort(arr, arr+n, 0) or sort(arr, arr+n, 1)*

Answer (score 4):

When you write `sort(arr, arr+n, compareInterval)`, the `compareInterval` function is not called immediately.  That would be `sort(arr, arr+n, compareInterval())` (which wouldn't work).

So `std::sort` doesn't get a `bool` value for its third argument.  It gets a pointer to the function `compareInterval`.  It can then use this pointer-to-function value to call `compareInterval` as many times as necessary with various pairs of `Interval` objects to figure out the correct order for the elements being sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The function you provide to `sort` as 3rd parameter is called whenever internal sort logic requires it (according to implemented sort algorithm). The sort function chooses with what parameters to call your function.
You can read more about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Instead of compare function you can write lambda directly in std::sort.

```
Interval arr[] =  { {6,8}, {1,9}, {2,4}, {4,7} };
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

std::sort(arr, arr+n, [](Interval& i1, Interval& i2) {return i1.start < i2.start;});
```

Comment: Writing lambda directly in std::sort comes up with the error message               
[Error] template argument for 'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)' uses local type 'main()::<lambda(Interval&, Interval&)>'

Comment: Will you please explain me why i was getting the above error

Comment: Maybe you use too old C++ version or compiler which doesnt't support lambdas. In this case you may code normal function and pass it to std::sort by pointer to function.